# How to use module variables in another tpl - product.tpl of my template?

Tags: php

I use the productcomments module, it has in its php file variables `$averageTotal` and `$nbComment`, which work in the module's .tpl file.

I would like to use them in the product prodct.tpl file in the main product description.

How can I use these variables? Can they be made with global variables so that they work in all tpl of my site? How to do it?

Comment: Is https://github.com/PrestaShop/productcomments the productcomments module you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, but version 9.3.4 , from https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/609811-free-module-product-reviews-comments-for-prestashop-17/